# Very basic _click query not working

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, sql

I have a very basic _click query like this:

```
SELECT SubscriberKey
FROM _Click
WHERE LinkName = 'XXX'
OR LinkName = 'XXX'
OR LinkName = 'XXX'
```

The XXX are ofcourse dummy text but in my query i have the real linknames and i am sure that are the right ones. I have no errors but the result in my DE is zero. Is there something that i missed?

My DE looks like this:

```
SubscriberKey
Emailaddress
JobID
URL 
EventDate
LinkName
EmailName
```

I want the other attributes as well but first i want to test this and extend it later. Hope you can help me.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What do you search for in LinkName do you search for your alias you set for the link or do you search for particular link urls? Because there are three different columns that deal with the link. Url, LinkContent and LinkName. As shown here [Link to _Click dataview documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_data_view_click.htm&type=5)

Comment: I would verify that the LinkName (aka link alias you set in your email) exists in the dataview.  As this seems to be the likely culprit for returning 0 results.

Answer (score 1):

First make sure that you have followed the [**documentation on Click Data View**](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_data_view_click.htm&type=5) correctly, with correct attribute types, length and nullable-properties.

In your SQL query, instead of specifying an OR statement per name, write it this way:

```
WHERE LinkName IN ('nameA', 'nameB', 'nameC')
```

It should work fine.

Comment: sorry i am new here. My answer is below.

Comment: Add all the fields to your Data Extension that are in the documentation link, including the ones you don't need. Make sure you use correct types, length and nullable-property on those that require it. Then run your query again.

Comment: I will do that. But that is not really necessary? And just for checking. The X in the _click view documentation (https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_data_view_click.htm&type=5) means nullable?

Comment: Correct, X means it should be nullable field. Haven't built Data View without the required fields, but I'll try and report back.

Comment: Is there something different if you have a enterprise edition?

Comment: Ok, it will work fine even if you specify only a couple of fields in your DE and SQL query. Just need to make sure the fields are correct type / length / nullable (if applicable). So in your case you can try running the Query first without specifying any LinkNames - if it works, double check that the Link Names are properly typed.

Answer (score -1):

I found the problem. In my activity i had the data action at Update. So when i dit the first run it didn't do anything. After setting the data action on overwrite everything worked fine.